# Multiple rules for setting up value in ObjectGears

Tags: objectgears

How can I set more rules for setting up value after changing a record?

I am used to use rule `Set` or `calculate` value but `ObjectGears` allow just one rule for this type. Depending on values from other columns I want to set naother columns in various way.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose Action type: Start a script. You define a single script with a cascade of conditions and value settings.

You can find a good example here:
https://doc.objectgears.cz/vcd/en-US/og_examples_setting_up_record_value